# No such table/undefined method 'each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm about as new as they come to Rails, so apologies if this is an obvious mistake.

I recently created a scaffold that added a "Quotes" table to a future store website. I put the appropriate models and controllers and  in a module, "Project." Now I try to link over to localhost:3000/quotes, and I get the following error message:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Project::Quotes#index
    Showing /Users/e/Documents/company/company-store/app/views/project/quotes/index.html.erb   where line #28 raised:

    SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: project_quotes: SELECT "project_quotes".* FROM "project_quotes"
    Extracted source (around line #28):


 </thead>

 <tbody>
   <% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= quote.first_name %></td>
       <td><%= quote.last_name %></td>
```

My controller page looks as follows:

```
    module Project
      class QuotesController < Project::BaseController
       before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

        def index
          @quotes = Quote.all
        end
```

(etc.)

I tried changing both the view page and the controller from @quotes.each to @project_quotes.each, and I get the same error message. When I change only the controller or the view, I get this error message instead:

```
    undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I've looked up StackOverflow responses to this kind of problem, but the most common response, that I haven't established the table yet, don't make sense, as this comes from a scaffold, and I ran rake db:migrate without incident.

```
    class CreateQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :quotes do |t|
          t.string :first_name
          t.string :last_name
    #More fields that say essentially the same thing (email, etc.)

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `FROM "project_quotes"` => SQL is looking for a table called "project_quotes" ; `create_table :quotes do |t|` => You told Ruby (or your scaffold, whatever) to create the table called "quotes". Try using `@quotes = ::Quote.all` to see if Rails will use project_quotes as table's name

Comment: I ran a migration to change the table name from `quote` to `project_quote` and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran a migration to change the table name from quote to project_quote and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the help!